# Set alarm using android manager?

Tags: android

OK... my app needs to be set off a few times a week depending what days the user picks. I know you can use datapicker. Is there anyway that i can auto add one date on to todays date as in today is 19/04/2011 is there any way i can go +1 and it bring it up to 20/4/2011?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. How about this?

```
long oneDayFromNow = System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

If you're wanting the DatePicker to automatically come up with the next day, you can use the updateDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) method. You could do something like this (assuming you already have a DatePicker view called dPicker):

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(oneDayFromNow);
dPicker.updateDate(mCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, please accept/check it. My reputation score thanks you. :)